# Watching local storage using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am using a module called ngStorage for handling local Storage operations.(https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). Lets say I set an object in local storage $localStorage.something = true;
How do I watch this object to find out if it is still available in local storage?
I'v tried :

```
$scope.$watch($localStorage.something,function(newVal,oldVal){
   if(oldVal!==newVal && newVal === undefined){
     console.log('It is undefined'); 
  }
});
```

Basically I am trying to watch for when a user removes the object from local storage manually through chrome's console.Is this even possible??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can try:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $localStorage.something; },function(newVal,oldVal){
   if(oldVal!==newVal && newVal === undefined){
     console.log('It is undefined'); 
  }
})
```

Comment: :O thanks I honestly thought it wasn't possible to watch for these kinda changes but you proved me wrong. It didn't even strike me to watch a function which returns what I actually needed to be watched. Thanks ^^

Comment: Doesn't work... I'm using ngStorage with exact copy of the code above, using a timeout to change the localStorage var; the watcher doesn't run.

Comment: @danm07 The solution works logically, Maybe the problem is something different because of ngStorage.

Comment: This works but `newVal !== undefined` not `newVal === undefined`